# How can display Entry Meta (author, date,tag) only at a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have removed meta section from all category pages but now I just want to show entry meta only at one category page. The code is here:

`<div class="entry-meta"><?php $cat_list = get_the_category_list();if(!empty($cat_list)) { ?><a href="<?php echo get_month_link(get_post_time('Y'),get_post_time('m')); ?>" ><?php echo get_the_date('M j, Y'); ?>"></a>Updated on: <?php the_modified_date('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_modified_date('g:i a'); ?>  by <?php echo ' ';?><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );?>">span itemprop="name"><?php echo get_the_author();?></a><?php } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate template for the specific category, named like:

category-slug.php
  or 
category-ID.php

Put the category code plus the part that you removed before in this template.

-
Edit: I probably misunderstood your question, because there is no question in your post. Your code should do the job (and might be better to maintain) but contains some errors. For instance a missing bracket after is_category('category-21') and I think also a missing curly bracket at the end.

Comment: I have updated the correct code. My website has multi categories but I want to show entry meta only at one particular category.

Comment: What you did previously, with `is_category(slug)` should do it, right? Why did you remove it?

Comment: I don't want to show entry meta on all category pages. I just want to display it on one category - tech news